# Matching exact words using Regular expressions

Tags: c#

I have the following code and this works for English matching using Regular Expressions but it doesn't work for Arabic words. In English, I am getting a count value

```
 string tobematched = "التعلیمیة";
    string sentence = "ھدف ھذه الأسئلة والأجوبة ھو مساعدة الولایات والمناطق التعلیمیة على الوفاء بالتزاماتھا القانونیة للتأكد من أن سیاساتھا";
    int count = 0;

    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(sentence, tobematched, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I did it well for your request bro,
Don't forget this line:

sentence= sentence.Replace( tobematched ,"التعلیمیة222" );

```
string tobematched = "التعلیمیة";
        string sentence = "ھدف ھذه الأسئلة والأجوبة ھو مساعدة الولایات والمناطق التعلیمیة على الوفاء بالتزاماتھا القانونیة للتأكد من أن سیاساتھا";
        int count = 0;
        MessageBox.Show(sentence.ToString());
        sentence= sentence.Replace( tobematched ,"التعلیمیة222" );
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(sentence, tobematched, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            count++;
        }
        //return count;
        MessageBox.Show(sentence.ToString());
```

I hope this can help you ^_^

[image]

Comment: I need to return count of exact matches.

Comment: Just remove the double back slashes for the comment line to be like this:
return count;

Comment: I am not getting count when I am trying OP code. Why a replace is required ? it doesn't require

Comment: I just posted a part of code where I have issues...I have no idea how to get count for arabic matching.The same code working well for English text. I am aware of removing backslahes but if you run this code , it doesn;t return count for me.

Comment: No problem bro, just give me some time to test something, then replying you ASAP ^_^

Comment: The code you have posted not at all related to my original issue

Comment: What do you want exactly? Getting count of matches strings, or replace those strings with another string?
Please clarify it?

Comment: Getting count of matches strings

Comment: If so, your code does it correctly and return the count of matches strings as well.
To make sure of that show the count up in the message like this:

MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());

Comment: it doesn;t execute the code. I mean its not going inside loop

Comment: Have a look at this picture on this link, please:
https://www.mediafire.com/view/ds65jhilgs5536m/ReplaceArabicText2.png/file

Comment: i tried to read from PDF ,In this case  it doesn't detect and I use itextsharp to read it and when I debugged c# , I am getting strings from PDf but this code doesn't detect match

Answer (score -1):

with:

```
Regex.IsMatch(_stringToCompare_, ^expresion$);
```

with the `^` you indicates where start you expression and `$` the end

in your case

```
Match match in Regex.Matches(sentence, "^"+ tobematched + "$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Mmm nevermind, that sentence is to compare equals strings, well if is counter use `IsMatch` to return if it match